# How to give a user with a limited shell, regular shell access?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, ssh, execute-command

I have a user lets say user1, this user has a limited shell and can only run very few & specific commands if they log into ssh, how do I switch the user to regular access if I'm root.

Comment: If this is a shell defined in /etc/passwd (end of the user's line), use `usermod -s` to assign a unrestricted shell to them (`/bin/bash`)

Comment: @xenoid Thank you that did it. `usermod -s /bin/bash $USER`

changed it from lshell to bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a shell defined in /etc/passwd (end of the user's line), use `usermod -s` to assign a unrestricted shell to them (for instance `/bin/bash`)